# How to solve $\int_0^{2} \text{Li}_2(\frac{x+i}{i+2})$ and $\int_0^{2} \text{Li}_2(\frac{x-i}{2-i})$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to solve the integral below

$\int_0^{2} \text{Li}_2(\frac{x+i}{i+2})$ and
$\int_0^{2} \text{Li}_2(\frac{x-i}{2-i})$

I try to find around the web and also here but I don't find anything.
Thank you to all for assistance.

Comment: There are many different possible antiderivatives / integrals with different solutions, so this cannot be answered with one result. A step-by-step solution would take up an excessively long message and thus be disproportionate. Questions that require something b are not welcome here on Stack Exchange... $$$$
Also, show us your attempts that we can really help you and not just solve the task for you.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance however. I don't find something that can help me to start the problem. No one discuss this kind of $ L_i $ integral type so I don't know how to start the solving process. thanks again

Comment: Then I will simply calculate a possible integral for you step by step...

Answer (score 0):

**How to solve $\int_{0}^{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) ~\operatorname{d}x$**

**forming antiderivative**

First you have to form the antiderivative. For that you should substitute the interior of the dilogarithm and then use integration by parts. Then you can substitute the interior of the logarithm, then integrate the logarithm, and then resubstitute.
This is what it looks like:

$$
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) ~\operatorname{d}x \quad\mid\quad a := \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}a}{\operatorname{d}x} &= \frac{1}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \quad\mid\quad \text{solve for } \operatorname{d}x\\
\operatorname{d}x &= (\mathrm{i} + 2) ~\operatorname{d}a\\
F(x) &= (\mathrm{i} + 2) \cdot \int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a\\
\\
\int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a &= \int 1 \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a \quad\mid\quad \text{partial integration}\\
\int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a &= a \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) - \int -\ln\left( 1 - a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a \quad\mid\quad b := 1 - a\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}b}{\operatorname{d}a} &= a \quad\mid\quad \text{solve for } \operatorname{d}a = 1\\
\operatorname{d}a &= -\operatorname{d}b\\
\int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a &= a \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) - \int \ln\left( b \right) ~\operatorname{d}b\\
\int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a &= a \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) - b \cdot \left( \ln(b) - b \right) \quad\mid\quad b := 1 - a\\
\int \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) ~\operatorname{d}a &= a \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) - \left( 1 - a \right) \cdot \left( \ln(1 - a) - \left( 1 - a \right) \right)\\
\\
F(x) &= (\mathrm{i} + 2) \cdot  \left( a \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( a \right) - a - \ln(1 - a) \cdot (1 - a) \right) \quad\mid\quad a := \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2}\\
F(x) &= (\mathrm{i} + 2) \cdot  \left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) - \left( 1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

**plug the limits in**

Now you can use your integral limits and you have the following possible result:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) ~\operatorname{d}x &= F(b) - F(a)\\
\int_{0}^{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) ~\operatorname{d}x &= F(2) - F(0)\\
\\
F(x) &= (\mathrm{i} + 2) \cdot  \left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \cdot \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) - \left( 1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) \right)\\
F(2) &= \text{is not defined}\\
\lim_{{x} \rightarrow {2}} F(x) &= \frac{2 + \mathrm{i}}{6} \cdot \pi^{2}\\
F(0) &= \mathrm{i} \cdot \operatorname{Li}_2\left( \frac{1 + 2 \cdot \mathrm{i}}{5} \right) - 2 - 2 \cdot \ln\left( \frac{4 - 2 \cdot \mathrm{i}}{5} \right) = -2.212348... + 1.08753... \cdot \mathrm{i}\\
\\
\int_{0}^{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) ~\operatorname{d}x &= \frac{2 + \mathrm{i}}{6} \cdot \pi^{2} + 2.212348... - 1.08753...  \cdot \mathrm{i}\\
\\
\int_{0}^{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{x + \mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i} + 2} \right) ~\operatorname{d}x &= 5.50221... + 0.55740... \cdot \mathrm{i}\\
\end{align*}
$$

**comment / hint**

You can now do the same with the other integrals. The steps are analogous to this integral.
Don't forget that there are infinitely many solutions, as well as many possible integrals, so your solution will depend heavily on the calculation method.

**calculator**

Since I can't / don't want to calculate that in my head, I used Wolfram|Alpha:

[$\lim_{{x} \rightarrow {2}} F(x) = \frac{2 + \mathrm{i}}{6} \cdot \pi^{2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5B%28i%2B2%29%20*%28%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B%202%7D*dilog%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29-%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29-ln%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29*%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%20%2B%202%7D%29%29%2Cx-%3E2%5D)

[$F(0) = -2.212348... + 1.08753... \cdot \mathrm{i}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28i%2B2%29%20*%28%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B%202%7D*dilog%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29-%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29-ln%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%2B2%7D%29*%281-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bi%7D%7Bi%20%2B%202%7D%29%29%20where%20x%3D0)

[$F(2) - F(0) = 5.50221... + 0.55740... \cdot \mathrm{i}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F3%20%2B%20i%2F6%29%20%CF%80%5E2-%28-2%20-%202%20log%284%2F5%20-%20%282%20i%29%2F5%29%20%2B%20i%20Li_2%281%2F5%20%2B%20%282%20i%29%2F5%29%29)

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious "pills".The problem was born when I tried to evaluate an integral containing a particular logarithmic-function. Thanks again